# Bash not sourcing code as expected

Tags: bash

I have these two scripts, `configScript.sh`and `genScript.sh`. The first one works just the way I want it to work. It adds the correct values into `options.sh` and `echo` the right message. However, I want `genScript.sh` to accept the current argument in `options.sh` and output the correct `echo`. As it is now when I run `genScript.sh` it returns `null` and I can't figure out why.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#configScript.sh
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 ) 
            echo "  Option 1 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh one
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION=$OPTION
EOF
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  Option 2 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh two
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION=$OPTION
EOF
            ;;
esac
}
func
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#genScript.sh
. options.sh
OPTION=$1
func2()
{
    if [ "$OPTION" == one ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    elif [ "$OPTION" == two ] ; then
        echo "Option two"
    else
        echo "null"
    fi
}
func2
```

I managed to get `genScript.sh` to work the way I want by removing `OPTION=$1`. When I do that `genScript.sh` will accept the value inside `options.sh` and will output the right `echo` . BUT when I remove `OPTION=$1` `configScript.sh` stops working as it should, it doesn't update `options.sh` with a new value anymore.

Comment: Have you tried just echoing `$1` in `genScript.sh` ? I'd probably stick `one` and `two` in quotes as well...

Comment: When I `echo` $1 it doesn't return anything but I don't know how to make it return the value in `options.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you want genScript to be called. I think you want to run genScript with command line argument and as-well as with sourcing from options.sh.

Below changes to genScript.sh would serve the purpose. It gives preference to command line when both command line and options.sh have values.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#genScript.sh
OPTION=""
. options.sh
[ "$1" ] && OPTION=$1
func2()
{
    if [ "$OPTION" == one ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    elif [ "$OPTION" == two ] ; then
        echo "Option two"
    else
        echo "null"
    fi
}
func2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put quotes around "one" and "two" in the second script and in the first script where it generates options.sh and added default value $OPTION to the OPTION var in the second script so now it works.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#configScript.sh
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 )
            echo "  Option 1 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh one
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION="$OPTION"
EOF
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  Option 2 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh two
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION="$OPTION"
EOF
            ;;
esac
}
func
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#genScript.sh
. options.sh
OPTION=${1-$OPTION}
func2()
{
    if [ "$OPTION" == "one" ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    elif [ "$OPTION" == "two" ] ; then
        echo "Option two"
    else
        echo "null"
    fi
}
func2
```

That is one of the most irritating problems. I don't know if you are using editor with syntax highlighting but you better be so you run easily over this type of issues.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `genScript.sh` still returns `null` when I run it in shell

Comment: I am testing it on GNU bash, version 4.1.2 and it works after I execute ./configScript.sh , type **1** or **2** and hit enter.

Comment: Oh, I get the point it works at first but then doesn't work after you type just ./genScript.sh, give me a minute to fix.

Comment: Here's the update that works which elegantly gets as a default value the one from file if $1 is not set. Also it's a good practice to quote vars values.